# chrome extension for 3d animaton of webpages

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

I am trying to build a chrome extension which will display the webpage content as

https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/showcase/gallery/

What I want to do is take the webpage's content in such frames and display the frames with the 3d animation as in the link. Is it possible in chrome?

How to get such a frame then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether or not what you linked to can really be called an extension, or a plugin. It's really just using a jQuery or JavaScript carousel with CSS3's 3D features, which are part of the CSS3 spec. Strictly speaking, if you were to run this code in a newer version of Chrome, it would work just the same.

Comment: u didnt get my question..i want to make the webpages appear like that.for example if a website has got two pages,then those pages will appear in frames like that.

Comment: _Any_ given website, or just one you develop?

Comment: Alright, how familiar are you with ChromeDevTools? How about Java and Eclipse?

Comment: ya i am pretty much familiar with java and eclipse

Comment: I don't want to digress from answering your question too much, but, in addition to this plugin likely being quite complex (something you probably won't get the code for on StackOverflow), this thing would require some pretty impressive resources; it could bring many systems to a grinding halt, not to mention, drain laptop and netbook batteries very fast.